# how to add up numbers each time we click on a button

Tags: javascript

i want to make a program with one input where u put numbers into it. and each time you click, the sum will be added up by the numbers. this is how far i've come and i'm basically stuck here. so please help

```js
buttonAdd.onclick = function () {
  var inputTall = document.getElementById("inputTall").value;
  var a = parseFloat(inputTall);
  var b = 0;
  var c = a + b;
  document.getElementById("pOutput").innerHTML = c;
  d = c + a;
  document.getElementById("pOutput").innerHTML = d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/mystyles.css">
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>oppgave 24</title>
    <body>
      <h1>Summer tall</h1>
      <input id="inputTall">
      <button id="buttonAdd";>Legg til</button>
      <hr>
      <br>
      Nylig: <p id="nylig"></p>
      <hr> 
      Sum: <p id= "pOutput"></p>
      <script src="JS/code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

as you can see the d= c+a doesn't work and it keeps doubling up the last total.

Comment: You are initializing `c` as `a + b`, shouldn't you read c as the content of pOutput? You should probably use better variable names, it's harder to understand the logic you want with a,b ,c, d

Comment: thank you. i changed the variable names so its better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the total in a global variable:

```
var total = 0;
buttonAdd.onclick = function () {
    var inputTall = document.getElementById("inputTall").value;
    var a = parseFloat(inputTall);
    total += a;
    document.getElementById("pOutput").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: hello i also wonder if there's any possible to get rid of NaN when the input place is empty and the button is clicked?

Comment: `if(!isNaN(a)){
     total += a;
}`